# MySQL - Could not require management accessf for administration

Tags: mysql

I was working with MySQL workbench for the last couple of days. Yesterday I had my Windows 8 restarted and it made few updates in my computer by itself.

Today nothing is working on MySQL. I have error messages

```
unhandled eception: curent profile has no wmi enabled, error message code 10061...
```

and I found people saying that we should go on server administration, new server instance, manage server instance but I DON'T FIND ANYWHERE ON THE PROGRAM where is server administration.

Notes: I had uninstalled and re-installed MySQL, and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You could go through `Manage Server Instances` under `Server Administration”` column and close the screen once more.as explained [here](http://mygeekjourney.com/index.php/2013/01/27/bug-mysql-workbench-current-profile-has-no-wmi-enabled/).